# Automatic relationship for cloned items/cases

Tags: azure-devops, relationship, parent-child, clone

We use Azure DevOps and somehow when you clone an item now, it automatically adds a related work relationship (new clone is child of parent clone).  Is there a way to disable this?  It is happening for all work items and test cases.

Answer (score 1):

> it automatically adds a related work relationship (new clone is child
>   of parent clone)

For this issue ,I think it's by designed, Check this:

> Copy a work item when you want to create another instance of it and
>   optionally change its work item type. This action opens a form with
>   all fields filled out except for the Title. **A related link to the
>   original work item is created**. Also any parent link is copied over. No
>   history or attachments are copied over from the original work item.
>
> Source Link: [Copy or clone a work item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/copy-clone-work-items?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#copy-or-clone-a-work-item)

I think it is impossible to disable this feature. If you want to remove the related work relationship,you can do it manually.

[image]

Comment: This has not been the case for quite a bit until just a few days ago.  I understand how to remove a link, it's just very inconvenient when you are cloning something like a whole Test Suite into a different repo.

Comment: At present , work relationship can only be removed manually. You could submit a feature request in our [Develop Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site. Our PM and product team will kindly review your suggestion.